# Facebook comments loads very slow

Tags: javascript, facebook, performance

Facebook comments component load same JavaScripts many times and slows our page with 1.2+seconds  sometimes load for 29sec

Please help.

the script is in the bottom of the HTML source, we get it from Facebook developer API

http://www.247polls.com/polls/should-marijuana-be-legalized/

[image]

Comment: For me the link, what you write in question is loading about 2 seconds with all comments. In what region are you? Where is your server with your website located?

Comment: Toronto, Canada  but I test it from Philadelphia, US  the page without Facebook comments loads for 490-580ms, there is multiple loads of same javaScripts

Comment: https://www.webpagetest.org/

Comment: 10x Samuel my problem is Facebook comments component I can live with 550ms load for the rest    here other speed insides tool https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Will load your comments even if the page loading has not been completed:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR-APP-ID', version: 2.4, xfbml: true});

        if (typeof facebookInit == 'function') {
            facebookInit();
        }
    };

    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());


    function facebookInit() {
        console.log('Loading comments...');
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
</script>
```

Another thing to improve the speed is limiting the count of comments to show with `num_posts` to 5.

Keep rocking!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for reply , this code is OLD version there is new one https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3  no longer required "fb-root" element and I already have it on our website. Our problem is MULTIPLE LOADS OF same Facebook JavaScript see the attached image or view source of the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add `js.async=true;` and make sure you follow this doc :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

ref: https://geekflare.com/load-facebook-like-and-share-button-faster/

Comment: This is wrong. Dynamically inserted scripts (using document.createElement) execute asynchronously by default.